# How to enable hardware virtualization and DEP for Pentium E5200?

Tags: motherboard, hardware-virtualization

I just figured out that my processor is more awesome than I thought it would be.

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/hw64.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/hw64.png)

And here's the motherboard and CPU details:

[alt text http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/mobo.png](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/6863746/pics/mobo.png)

My only problem now, before I start to rock: how to enable those awesome features that are disabled?

As you can see above I have an ASRock motherboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The E5200 does not support [hardware virtualization](http://ark.intel.com/Product.aspx?id=37212&processor=E5200&spec-codes=SLAY7,SLB9T). It does support [DEP](http://www.itechtalk.com/thread3591.html) though. You'll need to install Windows 7 x64 if you want to be able to use 64-bit software.

Comment: yup, I saw that its contradicting with what securable is saying. So my processor does not support hw virtualization after all. how sad:(